# need help for substitute function in scheme

Tags: scheme

I need to write the function that can substitute the variables in the pairs of list into the list. for example `(subsitute-var '((p #t) (Q #f)) '(P and Q or Q))`

I have wrote some code

```
(define substitute   
  (lambda (A B list)     
    (cond      
     ((null? list) '())      
     ((list? (car list))
      (cons (substitute A B (car list)) (substitute A B (cdr list))))
     ((eq? (car list) A) (cons B ( substitute A B (cdr list))))      
     (else       
      (cons (car list) (substitute A B (cdr list)))))))

(define substitute-var
  (lambda (list var)
   (cond
     ((null? list) '())
     ((null? var) '())
     ((substitute (caar var) (car (cdr (car var))) list))       
      (substitute-var list (cdr var)))))
```

but the things is that it only substitute the first pair `(p #t)` and left the rest of the list like the same. I try to call `substitute-var` recursively, but it is also not working. so I need help. please help me thank you

Comment: and also the result of this substitute-var function should be like  (subsitute-var '((p #t) (Q #f)) '(P and Q or Q)) => (#t and #f or #f)

Comment: It is unfortunate to call the argument of substitute for `list`. The reason is that `list` is a builtin function. I suggest called it, say, xs, or similar.

Answer (score 1):

I think you got your `var` and `list` mixed up

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(define (substitute-var var lst)
  (if (or (null? var) (null? lst))
      '()
      (substitute (car var) (cadr var) lst)))

(define (substitute a b lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) '())
        ((eq? (car lst) (car a))
         (cons (cadr a) (substitute a b (cdr lst))))
        ((eq? (car lst) (car b))
         (cons (cadr b) (substitute a b (cdr lst))))
        (else (cons (car lst) (substitute a b (cdr lst))))))
```

Now, when tested with your example:

```
(substitute-var '((P #t) (Q #f)) '(P and Q or Q))
```

The procedure returns the expected answer:

```
(#t and #f or #f)
```